# Trying to measure, execution time in milliseconds on bash script

Tags: linux, bash

I need to measure the script execution time in milliseconds, I've written some test script but it's not working:

```
#!/bin/bash 
start=date +%s%3N
for i in {1..4};
do
    echo "i:$i"
    sleep 1

done
end=date +%s%3N
echo $($start -$end)
```

The `+%s%3N` is not found

Comment: Please take a look: http://www.shellcheck.net/

Comment: `start="$(date +'%s%3N')"`